# Flask is not found despite it should have been installed

Tags: python, pip

I am a beginner in Flask and I'm trying to code a web email application with flask and python. But right after trying to import Flask with the command `from flask import flask` it gives me the following Error:

```
> *Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\fabia\OneDrive\Desktop\Ehemaligenseite OneDrive for
> Business_files\Email_Contact_Formular.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from flask import Flask ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'*
```

But when I enter cmd there was the following answer:

```
> C:\Users\fabia>pip install flask
>     Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\fabia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (2.0.2)
>     Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in c:\users\fabia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from flask) (2.0.2)
>     Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in c:\users\fabia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from flask) (3.0.3)
>     Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in c:\users\fabia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from flask) (2.0.1)
>     Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in c:\users\fabia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from flask) (8.0.3)
>     Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\fabia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from click>=7.1.2->flask) (0.4.4)
>     Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\fabia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask) (2.0.1)
```

So why can't Pycharm find flask despite the cmd saying it should be installed?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install flask` command in `cmd` install flask in global environment.

But `Pycharm` has a virtual environment, so you need to install `flask` in virutal environment of `Pycharm`.

Open `Pycharm` and in it's `terminal` type `pip install flask`